# How to redirect users using "JavaScript Switch Statement"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using areacode to find out their province and redirect to a custom page. here's my JavaScript code for finding out where they are, using their areacode.

```
    function getProvince(pStrPhone) {
    var areacode = pStrPhone.substring(0, 3);
    switch (areacode) {
      case "403":
      case "780":
      case "587":
      case "825":
        return "AB";
      case "604":
      case "778":
      case "250":
      case "236":
        return "BC";
      case "204":
      case "431":
        return "MB";
      case "506":
        return "NB";
      case "709":
        return "NL";
      case "867":
        return "YT";
      case "902":
      case "782":
        return "NS";
      case "416":
      case "647":
      case "437":
      case "519":
      case "226":
      case "548":
      case "613":
      case "343":
      case "705":
      case "249":
      case "807":
      case "905":
      case "289":
      case "365":
        return "ON";
      case "418":
      case "581":
      case "450":
      case "579":
      case "514":
      case "438":
      case "819":
      case "873":
        return "QC";
      default:
        return "";
    }
  }
```

with this, I am redirecting users to a different page using the code below.

```
function redirect() {
      var province = $('#sfstate').val();
        if (province == 'BC') {
            $("#retURL" ).val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-bc.html");
        } else {
      if (province == 'ON') {
        $("#retURL" ).val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-on.html");
    } else {  
        $("#retURL" ).val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-other.html");      
      }
    }
    }
```

Now, I would like to add 'Other' for the getProvince function and redirect users to a default page, just in case someone types random number such as 111-111-1111.

here's my attempt.

```
    function redirect() {
      var province = $('#sfstate').val();
        if (province == 'BC') {
            $("#retURL" ).val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-bc.html");
        } else {
    if (province == 'ON') {
        $("#retURL" ).val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-on.html");
    } else {  
    if (province == 'AB','MB','NB','NL','YT','NS','QC') {
        $("#retURL" ).val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-other.html");    
    } else {  
        $("#retURL" ).val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-na.html");    
    } 
  }
    }
  }
```

and this is not working for some reason. Could you catch my mistake here, gurus?

Thank you very much,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (province == 'AB','MB','NB','NL','YT','NS','QC') {
    $("#retURL" ).val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-other.html");    
}
```

The condition is wrong. You could push the values in an array and use `indexOf` to find at least exact match with `province`.

```
var otherLetters = ['AB','MB','NB','NL','YT','NS','QC'];
if (otherLetters.indexOf(province) > -1) {
    $("#retURL" ).val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-other.html");    
}
```

Complete code looks like;

```
function redirect() {
  var otherLetters = ['AB', 'MB', 'NB', 'NL', 'YT', 'NS', 'QC'];
  var province = $('#sfstate').val();
  if (province == 'BC') {
    $("#retURL").val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-bc.html");
  } else {
    if (province == 'ON') {
      $("#retURL").val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-on.html");
    } else {
      if (otherLetters.indexOf(province) > -1) {
        $("#retURL").val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-other.html");
      } else {
        $("#retURL").val("https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-na.html");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir, you are a genius. You will have amazing lucks for at least 5 years.